# neo4django multiple inheritance

Tags: authentication, multiple-inheritance, neo4django

I was trying to create my model MyUser extending neo4django.auth.models.User,
so I can use the underlying authentication system. The problem is I want create also a superclass from which derive many methods and attributes
that are very common for my different kind of nodes.

I did this:

```
from neo4django.auth.models import User as AuthUser
class MyBaseModel(models.NodeModel):
    ....
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyUser(MyBaseModel,AuthUser):
    ...
```

but any operation on the model gives me
`ValueError: Multiple inheritance of NodeModels is not currently supported.`

Suggestions, workarounds?
Since MyBaseModel is essentially a container of methods and attributes, maybe a decorator that adds that fields would be an elegant solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're right- Multiple inheritance with multiple `NodeModel`-inheriting bases won't work.

However, could `MyBaseModel` inherit from `AuthUser`? If not, you can also mixin a non-`NodeModel` class. So if `MyBaseModel` is just a container for methods, you can just do

```
class MyBaseModelMixin(object):
    ....
```

and then inherit from that

```
class MyUser(MyBaseModelMixin, AuthUser):
    ....
```

Comment: I want to use MyBaseModel also for other classes, not only users,
so a Mixin would be better.
MyBaseModel defines some common attributes,
I want to be able to search (filter) on these too.
Do I have to write a NodeModelManager?
I kinda did that (named search), but when I try to use it:

`User.search.filter(_where_prov="Verona")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/tonjo/venv/tuned/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4django/db/models/query.py", line 1222, in __init__
    self._app_label = model._meta.app_label
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: And actually, MyUser inherits from MyBaseModel (mixin) only methods, no attributes :( Why is that?

Comment: Hm, I'd really need more information to help with that. Maybe you could update the question with your newest efforts?

Comment: Having other problems, I [asked another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878290/neo4django-mixin-inheritance-problems)